# SQL Server - retrieving stored files from DB to filesystem

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server database we have files stored in a table.

We want to extract files from DB to filesystem

The files are html, xls, pdf, image formats.

Please advise options to retrieve information with minimum programming effort.

1. Can this be done directly from database using some SQL function / TSQL code?
2. Can this be done by ASP.net?
3. Can we export records as XML file and work on the attachments?

Thanks.

Comment: You're not going to get a very welcome response here my friend because you haven't tried anything yourself, you're simply soliciting that people write it for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I am not into SQL Server programming. This is the reason I want to focus my efforts on exactly what I need to do, let it be programming BUT! the efforts should not be just hit and trial. Thanks for your ultimate guideline.

Comment: Since you mention ASP.NET [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902421/how-to-download-a-file-stored-in-sql-db-in-binary-format) may help. But this is a very common question and there are many answers already on this site and elsewhere. As Michael suggested, you will get a much better response if you do your own research, try a solution and ask for help on specific issues.

Comment: Thanks everyone I will proceed with the development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is stored as BLOB, then you can simply query that column like any other column in SQL Server. And if you are using Filestream to store files into file system, then this [MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695918.aspx) should help you.